# Работа с потоками "Процесс не может получить доступ к текстовому файлу"

Tags: c#, task

Во время работы программы в текстовый файл записывается всегда по разному 4-13 строк, а после вызывается исключение "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу"

Запуск (в списке "ip_list" 16 ip адресов)

```
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach (string ip_send in ip_list)
            {
                Task t = Task.Run(() => TelnetConnect_chekvers(ip_send));
                tasks.Add(t);
            }
```

Функция

```
static async void TelnetConnect_chekvers(string ip_send)
{
        using (StreamWriter fstream = File.AppendText(@"save\data.txt"))
        {
             await fstream.WriteLineAsync("данные ...");
        }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118657/discussion-on-question-by-tand--------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял дискуссию, ваша функция `TelnetConnect_chekvers` делает больше, чем простую запись в файл. Раз так, ваш файл является по сути *разделяемым ресурсом*, и обращения к нему необходимо синхронизировать. Проще всего, наверное, использовать семафор, т. к. его не нужно обязательно отпускать в том же потоке, в котором взяли. Ваш код с учётом мелких исправлений будет выглядеть так:

```cs
static async Task TelnetConnect_chekvers(string ip_send, SemaphoreSlim fileAccessToken)
{
    // тут та работа, которая вам нужна до записи
    try
    {
        await fileAccessToken.WaitAsync(); // получаем эксклюзивный доступ
        await File.AppendAllTextAsync(@"save\data.txt", "данные ...");
        // ну или AppendAllLinesAsync, если строк несколько
    }
    finally
    {
        fileAccessToken.Release();
    }
}
```

а вызывающий код — так:

```cs
var fileAccessToken = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (string ip_send in ip_list)
{
    Task t = TelnetConnect_chekvers(ip_send, fileAccessToken);
    tasks.Add(t);
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

или просто

```cs
var fileAccessToken = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
await Task.WhenAll(ip_list.Select(ip_send =>
       TelnetConnect_chekvers(ip_send, fileAccessToken)));
```

---

Более правильное концептуально решение, как мне кажется — не записывать результат файл внутри задания, а возвращать его как результат. Тогда необходимость в синхронизации вовсе отпадёт, и ваш код упростится вот до такого:

```cs
static async Task<string> TelnetConnect_chekvers(string ip_send)
{
    // тут та работа, которая вам нужна до записи
    return "данные ...";
}
```

и вызов

```cs
var texts = await Task.WhenAll(ip_list.Select(ip_send => TelnetConnect_chekvers(ip_send)));
await File.WriteAllLinesAsync(@"save\data.txt", texts);
```

или более изящно, без материализации списка строк:

```cs
var tasks = ip_list.Select(ip_send => TelnetConnect_chekvers(ip_send));
using (var f = File.AppendText(@"save\data.txt"))
{
    foreach (var task in tasks)
        await f.WriteLineAsync(await task);
}
```

(к сожалению, нету перегрузки `File.WriteAllLinesAsync`, принимающей на вход `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`).

Comment: Если говорить втором вашем варианте с возвратом значений то тут мне нужен Task.Run в любом случае. Так как в telnet подключении используется CancellationToken. Есть решение с Task.Run  и возвратом значений?

Comment: @Tand: А зачем вам Task.Run? У вас синхронная работа с telnet-ом? Покажите код. В качестве `CancellationToken` можно использовать `CancellationToken.None`, если вам в реальности не нужно останавливать задания.